# How to connect solr node using scala?

Tags: java, scala, solr, cassandra, solrj

for eg: 
using solr HTTP API

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/test.route/select?q=*:*&indent=true&shards.info=true&route.partition=nike|2,reebok|2
```

here we are using localhost to connect solr node.

but is same CQL query how to use localhost:

```
SELECT * FROM test.route WHERE solr_query='{"q" : "*:*", "route.partition" : ["nike|2","reebok|2"]}'
```

How to apply above CQL query in solr host(XX.XX.XX.XX:8983) using scala??

Answer (score 0):

This might alter slightly depending on which driver you're using but basically just connect to your node/cluster using the driver, then run the CQL query.

Comment: using cassandra connection to connect cassandra host. eg:
val config = new SparkConf(true)
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "XX.XX.XX.XXX")

but how for solr node?